# Does the Interrail pass cover trains between Paris Gare du Nord and Franconville?

Tags: tickets, paris, interrail

I was looking over the metro card possibilities as I will be staying with a friend in Paris who lives in Franconville. But then it occurred to me that my Interrail pass might already cover those journeys and save me spending an extra 31 euros for a 10 trip pass.

So does the Interrail pass cover small domestic journeys like that? Franconville is in Paris Zone 4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.raildude.com/train/paris-metro-rer-t781.html#p9934) (june 2009) quoting a mail from SNCF, Transilien network does not accept Interrail.

Answer (score 9):

No, [Interrails works on](http://www.interrailnet.com/countries/france/trains-france)

- TGV: high speed trains, reservations are required
- Thalys: high speed trains, reservations are required
- TEOZ: intercity trains, reservations are required
- Corail: intercity trains, reservations are recommended but not required
- Artesia: high speed trains, reservations are required
- Eurostar: high speed trains, reservations are required
- TER: regional train, reservations are not required.

And Paris-Franconville is a suburbian [Transilien](http://www.transilien.com/).